# Redirect Page With Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I did some research on this topic but i cant run this id is not send to page.

listdata.php

```
<td class="text-center" style="min-width:130px;">
    <button style="width:100%" class="btn btn-primary detail-customer" data-id="<?php echo $m->id; ?>">Bilgi</button>
</td>
```

ajax.php

```
$(document).on("click", ".detail-customer", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('customers/info'); ?>",
        data: "id=" + id
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        window.location = "customers/info";
    })
})
```

controller:

```
public function info()
    {
        $data['page'] = "customer_information";
        $data['userdata'] = $this->userdata;
        $id= trim($_POST['id']);

        print $id;
        //$this->template->views('customers/info', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you naming your ajax file as `Ajax.php`? is that a `PHP` file? It definitely should be a `js` file.

From what I know from Jquery and Ajax, `url` key takes the location of the PHP file, and the `data` key should be passed as an object. Take these two files as an example:

**Ajax.js**

```
$(document).on("click", ".detail-customer", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/absolute_path/to/php_file.php",
        data: {my_id:id, my_custom_key: "my_custom_value"},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        window.location = "customers/info";
    })
})
```

**Php_file.php**

```
<?php
$id = $POST["my_id"];
$customValue = $POST["my_custom_value"];
$response = ["message"=> "We took your id which is $id and your custom value which is $customValue"];
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

This is a very basic example of how to use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
$(document).on("click", ".detail-customer", function() {
    
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url('customers/info'); ?>",
            data: {"id":id},
            Content-Type:"json"
        });
        .done(function(data) {
            window.location = "customers/info";
        })
    });
```

"we do not read your complete controller code
if your code is correct total then please
first convert data in json then
return it.
"

```
public function info()
    {
        $data['page'] = "customer_information";
        $data['userdata'] = $this->userdata;
        $id= trim($_POST['id']);
        echo json_encode($id);
        //$this->template->views('customers/info', $data);
    }
```